# Does having a multiple trackPageview properties affect the visit count in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to adjust for an error we had on our site when 2 of the same `trackPageview` properties was up on our site.

Does having 2 `trackPageview` calls double the "visits" in Google Analytics? I know it doubles the `pageviews`, but based on what I'm reading in Google Analytics, it shouldn't double the visits.

Answer (score 1):

I just gave this a try and created a duplicate Universal Analytics Tag in the Tag Manager for our Website. In Real Time View I showed up as a single visitor (even though two trackers where created), so I'd say visits are not affected by double page calls.

Comment: Looking at my data now based on the date I was able to figure out when the additional trackpageview code was added and it looks like visits stay flat when everything else doubles.

Thanks for testing it out also!